# How to upload file to AWS s3 in Lumen

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, lumen

I am writing an application in Lumen, to provide APIs to the frontend framework. I am struggling with file upload to S3. 
Steps I followed.

- Configured .env file with

> AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>       AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=nXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>       AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=me-south-1
>       AWS_BUCKET=your_bucket_name
>       AWS_URL=https://apigateway.me-south-1.amazonaws.com

- Using composer installed AWS SDK for Laravel

  composer require aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel:~3.0
- Now wrote the function like this

  ```
  public function upload(Request $request)
  {
      $image = $request->file('image');
      $imageFileName = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $s3 = Storage::disk('s3');
      $filePath = '/venue/' . $imageFileName;
      $s3->put($filePath, file_get_contents($image));
      return response()->json(['status' => true, 'data' => $imageFileName], Response::HTTP_OK);
  }
  ```

It would be really great if someone can share an article or full tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: Check this
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-amazon-s3-file-upload-tutorial-part-1example.html

Comment: Thanks @NiravBhoi, here I am using Lumen, so it would be okay?

Comment: Yes It will be because lumen is child of laravel. But create backup first.

Comment: I know, but some of the features are not available in Lumen. Anyway, I will try with the package you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the this dependency:

```
composer require --with-all-dependencies league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 "^1.0"
```

see:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem